# How to change the text value of the button everytime it is being clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below I have jquery code and table. The jquery code is to toggle the div element called "divrep" everytime the reply button is click. What I want is I want the reply button to change the text value everytime it is being click.
So initially, the text value of the button is "Replie(s)". I want to change it to "Hide Replies" when it is click, and back to "Replie(s)" again when it's click again. How to add a script on my code to do this? Thanks...

**Jquery:**

```
$(function () {
  $('.Reply').click(function () {
  $(this).closest('p').next('.divrep').toggle(!$(this).closest('p').next('.divrep').is(":visible"));
   // How to insert a code here to change the text value of the reply button in every click?
 });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<table id="mytable">  

    <tr >
        <td class="tdstyle" >

  <div style="font-weight:bold;">  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name) </div> 

   <p class="comment more" style ="white-space: pre-line; margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px; border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px; max-width :500px; min-height :5px;  display :block; background-color: #CCCCFF">  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.comment) </p>
  <p> <input type="button" id="like" name="like" value="Like" style="color:blue;border:0px;background-color:inherit;cursor:pointer" /> <input type="button" class ="Reply" name="Reply" value="Replie(s)"  style="margin-bottom:0px;color:blue;border:0px;background-color:inherit;cursor:pointer" /></p>                                                                                                                                 
   <div id="divReply" class ="divrep" style="display:none; position:relative;left:50px; overflow:auto;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px">
           <table>

                 <tr >

                     <td >
                         <div style="font-weight:bold;"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.name) </div> 

                     <p class="comment more" style ="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;white-space:pre-line; border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px; max-width :445px; min-height :5px;  display :block; background-color: #CCCCFF;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.reply)  </p>

                   </td>
                 </tr>

            </table>      

   <div> 
       <div class="editor-field" style="display:none; margin-bottom:5px;margin-top:5px">  
          <input type="text" id="comidvalue" name="id" class="id" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)" />
       </div>

       <br />
       <input type="text" id="namerep" name="name" class="name" style="width:445px;resize:none" />

      <br />
      <textarea id="reply" name="reply" class="reply" style="width:445px;height:100px;resize:none" ></textarea>

         <br />

       <input type="button" class="postrep" value="Post Reply" name="butname" style="cursor:pointer" /> 

     </div>
            <br />

  </div>
        </td>       
    </tr>


</table>
```

Comment: What about a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Can't you just take id of reply button if you have only one reply button??? Instead of taking class?

Comment: @DH__ I can't use the id because I forgot to tell you that inside the table there is looping that is why I used class. Do you have in mind what code to add on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to set the text value using the visibility state of `divrep`

```js
$(function () {
    $('.Reply').click(function () {
        var $divrep = $(this).closest('p').next('.divrep').toggle(!$(this).closest('p').next('.divrep').is(":visible"));
        $(this).val($divrep.is(':visible') ? 'Hide Replie(s)' : 'Replie(s)')
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">  
    
    <tr >
        <td class="tdstyle" >
            
            <div style="font-weight:bold;">  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name) </div> 
            
            <p class="comment more" style ="white-space: pre-line; margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px; border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px; max-width :500px; min-height :5px;  display :block; background-color: #CCCCFF">  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.comment) </p>
            <p> <input type="button" id="like" name="like" value="Like" style="color:blue;border:0px;background-color:inherit;cursor:pointer" /> <input type="button" class ="Reply" name="Reply" value="Replie(s)"  style="margin-bottom:0px;color:blue;border:0px;background-color:inherit;cursor:pointer" /></p>                                                                                                                                 
            <div id="divReply" class ="divrep" style="display:none; position:relative;left:50px; overflow:auto;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px">
                <table>
                    
                    <tr >
                        
                        <td >
                            <div style="font-weight:bold;"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.name) </div> 
                            
                            <p class="comment more" style ="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;white-space:pre-line; border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px; max-width :445px; min-height :5px;  display :block; background-color: #CCCCFF;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.reply)  </p>
                            
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                </table>      
                
                <div> 
                    <div class="editor-field" style="display:none; margin-bottom:5px;margin-top:5px">  
                        <input type="text" id="comidvalue" name="id" class="id" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)" />
                    </div>
                    
                    <br />
                    <input type="text" id="namerep" name="name" class="name" style="width:445px;resize:none" />
                    
                    <br />
                    <textarea id="reply" name="reply" class="reply" style="width:445px;height:100px;resize:none" ></textarea>
                    
                    <br />
                    
                    <input type="button" class="postrep" value="Post Reply" name="butname" style="cursor:pointer" /> 
                    
                </div>
                <br />
                
            </div>
        </td>       
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This doesn't change the text value of the button with a class = "Reply". Why you're using the divrep? divrep is the div element to be toggled but that is not my concern. My concern is to change the value of the reply button.

Comment: @timmack I thought `Reply` was an anchor element.... since it is a `input` use `.val()`

Comment: Thank you johnny. It's now working. The reason why it wasn't working on the first post because you forgot to add this var $divrep

Answer (score 1):

For `<input>` button, You can pass a function to the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val) method that checks the current value and returns the new value to be set accordingly:

```
$(".Reply").val(function(i, value){
    return (value=="Replie(s)") ? "Hide Replie(s)" : "Replie(s)"
});
```

---

For `<button>` elements, you can do the same using the [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text) method.

Comment: I tried that but that won't return the text value that is being set. But this one will,  $(this).val($divrep.is(':visible') ? 'Hide Replie(s)' : 'Replie(s)')

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your JS (instead of your //commented line):

```
$(this).val($(this).val() == "Replie(s)" ? "Hide Replies" : "Replie(s)");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/the_julo/tnx5gd6u/2/

Comment: Just noticed that my answer is just a shorthand of T J's. 
I'll leave it in case it's useful to someone.